# aura_prod.js:688 taking too long to load (salesforce)

Tags: lightning, aura

[image: network perfomance]

The elements on the page only start to appear after this script ends and it takes too long.
Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: What component is being loaded, is it a custom or standard one?

Comment: almost everything on the screen: a CMS Collection, a Customizable User Profile Menu, the Header, the Footer
all these elements only appear after this script finish